# Insert element with sqlite3

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I Would like to insert some elements in my sqlite database but it display nothing on the output:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var file = "Res.db";
var exists = fs.existsSync(file);

if(!exists) {
  console.log("Creating DB file.");
  fs.openSync(file, "w");
}

var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);

function insertScore(sc, id){
console.log("Insert.");
db.run("INSERT INTO Score (score, uid) VALUES (?,?)", sc, id);
    console.log("End Insert.");
}

function createTable() {
console.log("Creating Table.");
  if(!exists) {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE Score (score TEXT, uid TEXT)");
  }
}

function closeDb() {
    db.close();
}

createTable();
insertScore("18.59", "toto");
db.each("SELECT uid, score FROM Score", function(err, row){
console.log(row.score + "  =  " + row.uid);
});
closeDb();
```

I'm not sure about the correct way to insert data. I'm new with all web stuff. I just used sqlite because it's for a small private project, and to practice a little bit the web environment.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This code works fine for me, but the first time you are running `INSERT` before creating the table. Once the table exists the code should work fine, though

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm never calling INSERT before creating my table,  am I ?

Comment: Ok please, if anybody have a clue, I have a no such table Score error. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears the run is an async calls so... well that's fantastic |°_°|